Are there any clues as to how similar other players' experiences were to Arisu's?
Warning: massive spoilers for the end of Alice in Borderland follow; don't read further if you don't want anything spoiled.  Because the entire question is a spoiler, it won't be included in spoiler tags.
At the end of Alice in Borderland, all the surviving players who chose not to remain in the borderland as citizens are revived in the aftermath of the disaster in the real world.  Many of them have injuries consistent with events that took place in the borderland:

Usagi has her left wrist bandaged (borderland: cut her wrist) and a badly injured right leg (borderland: knifed by the King of Spades)
Kuina appears to be favouring her left side where she was stabbed by the King of Spades
Niragi has suffered extensive burns
Heiya has the same left leg amputation she had in the borderland

We now know that what we saw was Arisu's experience of the borderland, but it was peopled with everyone else who was actually caught in the same disaster.
If Arisu's experience was the same as everyone else, then ultimately dozens of people's fates (if they lived or died) came down to whether or not Arisu finally decided to listen to the woman who he supposedly loved, and who was his biggest help and support.
I find that reading unsatisfying, but the alternative is that everyone else who survived had their own set of experiences that mirrored the same outcomes.  (Though it's possible those experiences were more personal and didn't have such a large cast.)  For example, regardless of whether or not Chishiya had an encounter with the King of Diamonds, he still wakes up determined to rethink his life.
I've only read the first few chapters of the manga (and wasn't really drawn to continue), and I haven't read any of the follow-on works.  Is it ever suggested how other people experienced the borderland?  (Anything that Asō-san has said on the subject would also be noteworthy.)

Did I find ep.8 frustrating?  Yes, I found it frustrating.  Can you tell?

You can't actually spoil the end of the series. ;). The third season does not come out until next year. So bear in kind that what you think you know at the end of the season is very likely not what you know.

@Adamant Everything I've read indicates that the end of season 2 corresponds to the end of the original manga.  I'll consider season 3 skeptically on that basis.

I'm not sure what that means considering that it will be part of the narrative of the show, so the correct answer to any question about the show will depend on it. If you only mean to ask questions about the manga, which differs from the show in some relevant aspects even before the end of the second season, it might be worth editing to indicate that.

But anyway, even if everything we know is true, if it looks deeply unfair, that is because it is. There have been countless games that in all likelihood, some people had no real chance of winning. Many people are dead by the end, presumably kicked out of the borderland to an afterlife or annihilated altogether, because of these games, often because of bad or even good decisions that other people made in the games. The small unfairness of the few remaining people depending on a single decision is the icing on a brutally unfair cake.

@Adamant It could equally be argued, given that people in the borderland sustained exactly the same injuries they had in real life, that certain people were going to die regardless (since in real life they died).  We have no evidence that it was ever possible to save everyone in the borderland, or even that everyone could save themselves.  The source (and timing) of injuries in the borderland obviously differs from real life, so could the causes of death.  Maybe Karube and Chota simply never had a chance at winning; they were always "fated" to die.

Another important thing is that there are sequels to the manga. One is just a spinoff, but the other was serialized right after the live action show premiered, and could quite plausibly also be the basis for the third season.
Or it could outright contradict the route that the show takes. So I feel like the best approach here is to either (a) ask only about the manga, which could incorporate information from the sequels, or (b) wait for the third season of the show for a complete answer, accepting that it might invalidate some of the assumptions here.
